# What is the default connection timeout for a PySQLPool connection?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am unable to find the piece of info. In the documentation of [PySQLPool](http://pythonhosted.org//PySQLPool/reference.html), we have the following class to create a new connection object:

```
 class PySQLPool.PySQLConnection([host[, user[, passwd[, db[, port]]]]], **kargs)
```

One of the kwargs is:

> connect_timeout - number of seconds to wait before the connection
>   attempt fails.

What is the default value for `connect_timeout`? Is it the same as the MySQL default value which is 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/nerdynick/PySQLPool/blob/master/src/PySQLPool/connection.py) it shows:

```
 connection_timeout = datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)
```